# Bloggish Project MySQL Database Design Issues

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm not the greatest with MySQL. This is my first project that uses it to a great degree. The idea is, I'm designing a system that can take a blog-type article, and associate tags with it (in my code, I refer to the tags as categories). Here is the MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_categories
(
    category_id int(4) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    category_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    is_service tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id),
    UNIQUE (category_name),
);

CREATE TABLE tb_blog_entries
(
    blog_entry_id bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    blog_entry_title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    blog_entry_subtitle varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    date_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    blog_entry_content TEXT NOT NULL,
    author varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    publish_anonymously tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (blog_entry_id)
);
```

My problem is, I need to map the one or more categories selected to each blog post. I don't want to add a csv-like column to the blog entry table containing all the category ids, as there would surely be a better way. However, I have no idea. What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a many-to-many relationship between the two tables. To achieve this you must use an intermediate table, like this

```
CREATE TABLE tb_blog_entries_categories
(
    blog_entry_id bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    category_id int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(blog_entry_id,category_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (blog_entry_id) REFERENCES tb_blog_entries(blog_entry_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES tb_categories(category_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a N:N relation, this means a third table.

table post_categories, with 2 fields:

1. id_post
2. id_category

Then you can fill this table with the posts and their related categories:

```
id_post  | id_category
7        | 2
7        | 3
4        | 2
...
```